# PL/SQL procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compiler-errors

I am new to PL/SQL and I was wondering why this procedure block is throwing me an error?

```
    declare 

    airFAA airport.faa_id%type;
    airUse airport.airport_use%type;
    airHours airport.attendance%type;

    procedure get_AirportHours( airFAA in airport.FAA_ID%type, airUse out airport.airport_use%type, airHours out airport.attendance%type) is

    BEGIN

    select airport_use, attendance
    into airuse, airhours
    from airport
    where faa_id = airfaa;

    End;
```

and this is my error

```
    Error report:
    ORA-06550: line 16, column 4:
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

    begin function package pragma procedure form
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:`
```

Comment: What is the code trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to create a stored procedure `get_AirportHours`?  Or are you trying to run an anonymous PL/SQL block that declares a local procedure `get_AirportHours` (which would no longer exist once the anonymous block completes)?

Comment: For right now just an anonymous block that declares a local procedure eventually I would like to create an stored procedure from it. I am trying to create a procedure that allows me to input an FAA_ID like 'LIT' and I should be able to retrieve the intended use for that airport for example 'open to the public' and airHours as '24/7'. In the airport table FAA_ID is the primary key.

Comment: OK.  So you want to create an anonymous block that declares a local procedure.  What do you want the block to actually do?  I would assume that you'd want the block to call your local stored procedure (otherwise, why bother declaring it).  Are you saying that you want the anonymous block to call the stored procedure passing in a value of `LIT`?  What do you want to do with the `OUT` parameters?  Do you want to, say, print them to `dbms_output` within your anonymous block?

Comment: Correct I want to be able to call from this procedure like this <pre>'begin 
faa_id := 'LIT';
get_AirportHours( faa_id, airUse, airHours);
dbms_output.put_line( 'This airport is ' || airUse || ' and hours of   operation are ' || airHours );

   end; '</pre>

Comment: I'm sorry I can't seem to highlight my code in the comments :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Sorry guys but I guess my code was right, I just went to re-load my database and magical things happened that is all. Thanks for all of your help!

```
declare 

airFAA airport.faa_id%type;
airUse airport.airport_use%type;
airHours airport.attendance%type;

procedure get_AirportHours( airFAA in airport.FAA_ID%type, airUse out airport.airport_use%type, airHours out airport.attendance%type) is

BEGIN

select airport_use, attendance
into airuse, airhours
from airport
where faa_id = airfaa;

end;
begin 
airFAA := 'LIT';
get_AirportHours( airFAA, airUse, airHours);
dbms_output.put_line( 'This airport is ' || airUse || ' and hours of operation are ' || airHours );

end;
```

Output as

```
anonymous block completed
This airport is Open to the public and hours of operation are Continuous
```